# Defining and projecting batch of raster images using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, raster, coordinate-system

Edit: the error was caused by spelling `.tif` as .tiff`.

The script ran fine before I added `InSR`, the input coordinate system.

I'm getting the following error:

`arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000445: Extension is invalid for the output raster format.
Failed to execute (ProjectRaster).`

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy, sys, os

InFolder = r"E:\ReprojectionScript"
OutFolder = r"E:\ReprojectionScript\test"
OutSR = arcpy.SpatialReference(26918) # NAD83 / UTM zone 18N
InSR = arcpy.SpatialReference(26996) # Missouri East
arcpy.env.workspace = InFolder

rasterList = arcpy.ListRasters()
for Ras in rasterList :
     inRaster = os.path.join(InFolder, Ras)
     outFileName = "{}.{}".format(os.path.splitext(Ras)[0], "tif") # Remove .sid and add .tif to Ras filename
     outRaster = os.path.join(OutFolder, outFileName) # Path and Filename of output raster (.tif)
     arcpy.ProjectRaster_management (inRaster, outRaster, OutSR, "", "", "", "", InSR)
```

Comment: Try replacing the optional parameters `""` with `"#"`

Comment: I tried replacing the `""` with `#` but it returned same error.

Comment: yeah sorry, that probably didn't help. jbalk's revised answer looks good though

Comment: Did you find a solution to this already? It appears as if you posted a solution as an edit. If that is the case, please either accept the existing answer or add an answer of your own so we can consider this question resolved.

Answer (score 2):

The error you receive is a result of passing a spatial reference object into a parameter that does not accept spatial reference objects.

From the tool description:

out_coor_system (Coordinate System):
  The coordinate system to which the input raster will be projected. The default value is set based on the Output Coordinate System environment setting.Valid values for this parameter are

- A file with the .prj extension.
- An existing feature class, feature dataset, raster catalog (basically anything with a coordinate system).
- The string representation of a coordinate system. These lengthy strings can be generated by adding a coordinate system variable to ModelBuilder, setting the variable's value as desired, then exporting the model to a Python script.

To fix your code try this (updated after reading Faith_Dur's comment):

```
OSR = arcpy.SpatialReference(26918) # NAD83 / UTM zone 18N
ISR = arcpy.SpatialReference(26996) # Missouri East
OutSR = OSR.exportToString()
InSR = ISR.exportToString()
```

Or This:

```
OutSR = "PROJCS['NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_18N',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',500000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-75.0],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9996],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',0.0],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]"
InSR = "PROJCS['NAD_1983_StatePlane_Missouri_East_FIPS_2401',GEOGCS['GCS_North_American_1983',DATUM['D_North_American_1983',SPHEROID['GRS_1980',6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM['Greenwich',0.0],UNIT['Degree',0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION['Transverse_Mercator'],PARAMETER['False_Easting',250000.0],PARAMETER['False_Northing',0.0],PARAMETER['Central_Meridian',-90.5],PARAMETER['Scale_Factor',0.9999333333333333],PARAMETER['Latitude_Of_Origin',35.83333333333334],UNIT['Meter',1.0]]"
```

Comment: OutSR.exportToString() will give the same outcome